# Counting groups in list

Tags: python, list, pandas

I'm trying to count the number of distinct groups of text labels in the list `blabla` in python. e.g

```
for i in blabla['Condition'].unique():
    print i
```

the output of which is:

```
no1 med1 48h
no1 med1 72h
no1 med1 96h
no1 med1 120h
no2 med1 48h
no2 med1 72h
no2 med1 96h
no2 med1 120h
no1 med2 48h
no1 med2 72h
no1 med2 96h
no1 med2 120h
```

I want to count amount of times the repeat (i.e. `48h`, `72h`, `96h`, `120h`) occurs in the particular list `blabla`. In this case 3 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
>>> ids = set(' '.join(item.split()[:2])
...           for item in blabla['Condition'].unique()))
# set(['no2 med1', 'no1 med1', 'no1 med2'])
>>> len(ids)
3
```

That is, treat the first two words of each item as its identifier, and count the number of unique identifiers.

(It is necessary to convert the list `item.split()[:2]` back to a string using `join`, because lists [cannot be used as set elements](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-hashable), which is required here to make them unique.)

Answer (score 1):

Number of *"48h"* in DataFrame

```
>>> df
     no   med hours
0   no1  med1   48h
1   no1  med1   72h
2   no1  med1   96h
3   no1  med1  120h
4   no2  med1   48h
5   no2  med1   72h
6   no2  med1   96h
7   no2  med1  120h
8   no1  med2   48h
9   no1  med2   72h
10  no1  med2   96h
11  no1  med2  120h
>>> df.hours[df.hours == "48h"].count()
3
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in method for this [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html#pandas.Series.value_counts):

```
In [9]:
df['hours'].value_counts()

Out[9]:
48h     3
120h    3
72h     3
96h     3
Name: hours, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Python's `collections.Counter` for this:

```
import collections

data = [
    "no1 med1 48h",
    "no1 med1 72h",
    "no1 med1 96h",
    "no1 med1 120h",
    "no2 med1 48h",
    "no2 med1 72h",
    "no2 med1 96h",
    "no2 med1 120h",
    "no1 med2 48h",
    "no1 med2 72h",
    "no1 med2 96h",
    "no1 med2 120h"]

for k, v in collections.Counter([entry.split()[2] for entry in data]).items():
    print '{:5} {}'.format(k,v)
```

This would display the following:

```
96h   3
120h  3
72h   3
48h   3
```